# facebook Graph api 2.2 issue

Tags: objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

How can i get the list of all friends using the graph api 2.2 and also i want to post the text on the friends wall. in iOS application

I tried:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id<FBGraphUser> result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
                          /* handle the result */

                          dicResult =(NSDictionary *) result;

                          NSLog(@"%@", dicResult);

                          [self.tblFriendListGroup reloadData];

                      }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can´t get ALL friends anymore, only those who authorized your App too.
- You can´t post on the wall of friends. That possibility was removed many years ago because it would always be spam.

Check out the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog?locale=en_GB

Comment: so how to solve this any how..? is there any of the solution..?

Comment: there is no solution. it just does not work - for very good reasons (privacy and spam).

Comment: ya, ok. will try something different option